# Javascript Re-establish window parent / child releationship when parent is closed

Tags: javascript

Ok, here's the scenario.

I have a page that opens a new window.
It then sets various properties in this new window such as parent url and parent window name.

The child window creates a javascript timer and does call backs to the parent window every x seconds.

The parent window is closed.

When the child timer elapses I see that the window.opener is now null.

How can I check to see if another window with the parent url and parent window name is open?
Then if I find a match how do I set this match window as the child's parent without reloading the child window?

Comment: Don't think you can do that - if you could, a page could see all the windows/tabs/pages you have open at this moment. Best way around this would be to have both communicate with a server.

Comment: I was afraid of that. I'll see what my options are there.

Comment: Usually for parent-child relationships such as this, you have the parent close the child when the parent is closed. Otherwise, there's no way to reconnect the child to the parent unless the child reopens the parent as a child, which complicates things more than necessary.

Answer (score 1):

I have NOT tested this in all major browsers.

```
// open the child window for first time
window.open('test.html','WindowName');
// re-assigns the reference for the same child window to a variable
WindowRef = window.open('','WindowName');
```

Note that url parameter is left blank and Pop up window name is the same. It refers to the same child window and assigns the reference object to variable "WindowRef".

The best part of the above code is that you can take the reference of the window regardless of the parent page refreshing.'

Copied from: 
http://www.daniweb.com/web-development/javascript-dhtml-ajax/threads/48485/parentchild-windows-references#post1323452

Comment: Tested and working on ie7-9, FF 17.0.1, Opera 12.11, Safari 6.0.2.

Comment: I believe the problem with this is that if the child window is still open with the same WindowName it would reload it. We have a java applet running in the child window and cannot have it reload because the users work would be lost.

Comment: Doesn't seem to reload for me. Found a page that uses this pattern. http://josephj.com/lab/2011/window-open-reconnect/demo.html